# How to synchronize scroll bars of the two list view in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, scrollbar

I have two list views. One for freezing the first column and second one for the remaining columns.now when user scroll horizatially the two list views are not synchronized.

Can you please throw some pointers.

THanks,
Naveen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small example for your reference.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" WidthRequest="120">
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding mylist}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding id}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding mylist}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding mes}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the cs code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Class1> mylist { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mylist = new ObservableCollection<Class1>
    {
        new Class1("Data 1", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa") ,
        new Class1("Data 2", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb" ),
        new Class1("Data 3", "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc" )
    };
        BindingContext = this;
    } 
}
```